# insert into textbox a different value from autocomplete query

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, select, autocomplete

I´m having some trouble with the autocomplete function from jquery. I need one of the fields from the query in my model (working with codeigniter btw) to return another value, I would appreciate any kind of help, thank you.

```
       $(function(){
        $('#buscador').autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: "home/get_cliente",

            select: function(event, ui){
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#buscador').val(ui.item.value);  
                $('#apellidos').val(ui.item.apellidos); 
            }
            });
        });
```

Comment: What is your problem specifically? Is it returning the wrong value now or is it not returning a value at all?

Comment: It´s not returning the value I want, for example. The autocomplete works, it returns the name and I can select it everything is correct, my problem is I want to return to a textbox other value from the table

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mf3L2qsx/3/ - can you tell what do you want to happen when an item is selected

Comment: Well, in my case, when I select the name from the customer I want it to return their last name.

Comment: Do you want the value stored in the input to be the last name after they select the full name from the dropdown?

Comment: Well not exactly, I want the value from the lastname to be selected in other input after I select the first name from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got my answer, I had to change the variable name in the array on the model like this:

model:

```
function get_cl($q){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->like('nombres', $q);
$query = $this->db->get('clientes');
if($query->num_rows > 0){
  foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
    $new_row['label'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['nombres'])); //build an array
    $new_row['value'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['id_cliente']));
    $row_set[] = $new_row;
}
  echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
}
```

}

Controller:

```
function get_cliente(){

if (isset($_GET['term'])){
  $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
  $this->autocompletado_model->get_cl($q);
}
```

}

JS:

```
       $(function(){

        $('#buscador').autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: "home/get_cliente",

            focus: function(event,ui){
                $('#buscador').val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            },
            select: function(event, ui){
                id_cliente = ui.item.value;
                $('#id_cliente').val(id_cliente);
                return false;  
            }
        });
```